# Passing JSON Object from Javascript to ASP.Net

Tags: c#, ajax, json, wcf

I am trying to pass the Json string sObject from javascript to c#. In c# I am trying to load data from this JSon string to a Object.
I get a Bad Request error in Javascript.

## C# Entity Object:

```
public class StatusEntity
{
    public string WorkOrderID { get; set; }
    public string JobID { get; set; }
    public string ClientID { get; set; }
}
```

## c# WCF Service:

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/updatestatus", Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public string updateStatus(List<StatusEntity> _objStatus)
{
    string sResult = string.Empty;
    try
    {
            // SOME CODE HERE
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        sResult = string.Empty;
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {

    }
    return sResult;
}
```

## Javascript Code:

```
function updateStatus() {
    var sObject = '[{"WorkOrderID":"9","JobID":"48","ClientID":"9"},{"WorkOrderID":"9","JobID":"48","ClientID":"10"}]';
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: "../JobMatchingService/updatestatus",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",

        // OLD CODE - NOT WORKING
        data: sObject,
        // NEW CODE CHANGES WORKING
        data: '{"_objStatus":' + _objStatus + '}',

        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        },
        error: function (xhr, options, error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: How are you deserializing the passed in JSON? Your web method expects a C# class.

Comment: I don't know what you mean? I get this using json.stringfy

Comment: Your method `updateStatus` expects a single `StatusEntity` but you're passing an array of them: `var sObject = '[{"WorkOrderID":"9","JobID":"48","ClientID":"9"},{"WorkOrderID":"9","JobID":"48","ClientID":"10"}]';`.  Either pass only one, or change the signature of your method to accept a `List<StatusEntity>`.

Comment: I changed the signature of my method to accept a List<StatusEntity>, but still get the bad request error. UPDATED the code.

Comment: Can you use your Browser's F12 tools to get the exact details of this Bad Request error - it might shed some light.

Comment: Hi Stephen.. Here is the error from browser Request URL:  http://localhost:19829/JobMatchingService/updatestatus
Request Method:  POST
Status Code:  HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Comment: Can you expand the XhrResponse part of the response you get, as it should contain some more details about the error.

Comment: If you get an exception, then you will not get `sResult` returned to you, since you rethrow.

Comment: how do i do that Stephen

Comment: Depends on the debugging tool, but in most cases when you are looking at network responses, you can see not only the response text but also the response body which should contain more detail (for example - the details of an Exception). Where are you reading this response from?

Comment: using firefox browser f12

Comment: I get this 
Request Error

The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details.

Comment: ok so in the "Net" tab when you POST you should see the result with a series of sub-tabs like "Headers", "Post", "Response", and then another tab depending on the content type sent back - could be JSON, XML, HTML, etc..what's in the "Response" tab and the tab beside it?

Comment: Params Tab:[{"WorkOrderID":"9","JobID":"48","ClientID":"9"},{"WorkOrderID":"9","JobID":"47","ClientID":"10"}]

Comment: Response Tab:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Request Error</title>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <p class="heading1">Request Error</p>
      <p>The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details.</p>

Comment: I think the key point in the Response Tab is "See server logs for more details." Do you know how to do that? Also, if you aren't able to inspect the server logs, then you might be able to ask WCF to emit more detailed errors.

Comment: I have made changes to the Javascript code and it started working.            // OLD CODE - NOT WORKING
        data: sObject,
        // NEW CODE CHANGES WORKING
        data: '{"_objStatus":' + _objStatus + '}',   Thanks everyone for the help..... :)

Answer (score 0):

Change _objStatus to a string in the method parameter, then use a try/catch to transform it into a StatusEntity like so:

```
var status = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<StatusEntity>>(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Made changes to the javascript, the data has to specified as below:

```
    // OLD CODE - NOT WORKING
    data: sObject,

    // NEW CODE CHANGES WORKING
    data: '{"_objStatus":' + _objStatus + '}',


function updateStatus() {
    var sObject = '[{"WorkOrderID":"9","JobID":"48","ClientID":"9"},{"WorkOrderID":"9","JobID":"48","ClientID":"10"}]';
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: "../JobMatchingService/updatestatus",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",

        // OLD CODE - NOT WORKING
        data: sObject,
        // NEW CODE CHANGES WORKING
        data: '{"_objStatus":' + _objStatus + '}',

        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        },
        error: function (xhr, options, error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
}
```